# What does the key " b'batch_label' " in cifar-10 unpickle by python use for?

Tags: python, machine-learning

When I unpickle cifar-10 by python, I get a dictionary with 4 keys:'batch_label','data','filenames','labels'. But I don't konw what the key 'batch_label' represent for. It's a 'bytes' type data, length is 21. I konw I needn't to know it when I train a network. But I'm still curious about it. Thanks for any reply. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cifar10 dataset you are donwloading is splitted in serveral batches.
Each batch has its own id (`batch_label`).

`data` is the actual batch if images, while `filenames` is the name of the images encoded. `labels`, of course, is the set of labels associated with the `data`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had thought no one would reply my question, but you replied all of my question! Thanks for you remembering me and replying my question sepcially. You are a very very kind man! ^_^